# Tick marks either side of dates in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, axis-labels

Ggplot adds ticks marks centrally using this code:

```
tibble(year = 2010:2020, count = sample(1:100, 11)) %>%
  mutate(year = paste0("01/01/", year)) %>%
  mutate(year = dmy(year)) %>%
  ggplot +
  geom_bar(aes(year, count), stat = "identity", width = 240, position = position_dodge(width = 0.1)) +
  scale_x_date(date_labels = "%y", date_breaks = "1 year") +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,100), expand = c(0, 0)) +
  theme_classic()
```

[image]

But I need tick marks either side of the year. I have photoshopped in the tick marks plot to show where I need them. What code can I use to add ticks marks either side of year?

[image]

Comment: It'll require some research, but you can use the `grid` package for customizing the tick-locations. (create a custom one with `grid.xaxis()`, or edit the `segments[ticks]` graphical object after creation)

Answer (score 1):

You can draw the tick marks yourself with `geom_segment()`, turn off the clipping and hide the default ones.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

tbl <- tibble(year = 2010:2020, count = sample(1:100, 11)) %>%
  mutate(year = paste0("01/01/", year)) %>%
  mutate(year = dmy(year))

ggplot(tbl) +
  geom_bar(aes(year, count), stat = "identity", width = 240, position = position_dodge(width = 0.1)) +
  geom_segment(aes(x = year, xend = year), y = 0, yend = -1, 
               colour ="black", position = position_nudge(x = 240/2)) +
  geom_segment(aes(x = year, xend = year), y = 0, yend = -1, 
               colour ="black", position = position_nudge(x = -240/2)) +
  scale_x_date(date_labels = "%y", date_breaks = "1 year") +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,100), expand = c(0, 0),
                     oob = scales::oob_keep) +
  coord_cartesian(clip = "off") +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(axis.ticks = element_blank())
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-04-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Comment: It's better to load the required packages (`c("dplyr", "ggplot2")`) than the entire `tidyverse`.

Comment: Yeah in principle I agree about this. However, whenever I can't directly reproduce someone's example because they didn't include libraries and I run into errors I recognise as tidyverse errors, I just load the entire tidyverse. My goal is to solve the problem, I'm not volunteering my time to tracing back the bare minimum of packages that the question forgot to include.

Comment: well that just takes a minute or less :) but I do agree that the OP should have provided a fully-reproducible (working on copy-paste) example, inclusive of the libraries required. +1